# MySQL Workbench generate this error

Tags: mysql-workbench

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS a LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 3

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    subject s INNER JOIN prerequisite p ON s.subject_code = p.subject_id)
AS a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do are derived tables
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/derived-tables.html

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    select * from subject s INNER JOIN prerequisite p ON s.subject_code = p.subject_id)
 AS a
```